# How to make my background just stay in the landing page?

Tags: html

Just like when you open a page, it will show up a background image, when i scroll it wont follow and it will just go over to other thing, just stay at the top of the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try fixed in css like

```html
<style>
    .foo {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
</style>
<div class="foo">
    <img src="path/to/your/picture" alt="">
</div>
```